# Can I write a keras callback that records and returns the total training time?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to record the duration of the training run for a keras model. I understand that I could just take the time per step and multiply it with the total number of steps but I suspect that time could vary based on the batch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `keras.callbacks.Callback()`. And, yeah you are right that time will vary based on the batch size.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

class TimingCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, logs={}):
        self.logs=[]
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.starttime = timer()
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.logs.append(timer()-self.starttime)

cb = TimingCallback()

model = Sequential()
# Your code
model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[cb])
print(cb.logs)
print(sum(cb.logs))
```

Read about it from [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/).

Comment: Why use `timeit`? Could the `time` module not have worked?

Comment: Yeah we could also have used `time.time()` in above case. In order to check, replace `timer()` with `time.time()`, but result would be slight different. See this: stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/…. Read second answer. That's I decided on to use `timer()` in above case.

Comment: Does anyone know why, when this above step is applied, this error is observed ? AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'logs' . I have applied the custom function, but not sure why this error keeps showing ?

Answer (score 10):

Why a callback ? You could just do:

```
from time import time

start = time()
model.fit(.....)
print(time()-start)
```

Comment: Cool! However, won't this also include the time taken to save weights or training history as well as any time spent in time consuming callbacks and other things that do not include training? Other than that, this approach is simplistic and works.

Comment: This approach have a problem when using a Nvidia GPU to train. Before the train actually starts, it has to load the cuDNN, wich takes a few seconds. So, the time you see in the `print(time()-start)` is actually larger than the actual time the network spent training. This can be an issue if you are training the same model `n` times (in a `for` loop for example) for statistical assessment of performance, because the first model will always take more time than the rest of models, when the cuDNN is already loaded.